# Proving $\overline{\ker(A-\lambda {\rm Id})^{r}} = \ker(A-\overline{\lambda}{\rm Id})^{r}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

Is there a simple proof of $\overline{\ker(A-\lambda {\rm Id})^{r}} = \ker(A-\overline{\lambda}{\rm Id})^{r}$, with $A \in M(n,\mathbb{R})$?

I think induction might work, but if there are other methods I'd rather accept them.

Any help or tip would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, can't find definition of $d$ in problem. Can you explain what is $d$?

Comment: @K.K.McDonald You mean Id? Identity matrix

Comment: What is $M(n,\mathbb{R})?$ Is the overline the closure of the set?

Comment: @Botond The first are the real matrix of size $n$. The second is the conjugated of the subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remember the definitions. $x\in \overline{\text{Ker}(A-\lambda)}$ means 
$$
(A-\lambda)\bar x=0
$$
Then if you take complex conjugate and use $\bar A=A$
$$
(A-\bar\lambda)x=0
$$
and $x\in\text{Ker}(A-\bar\lambda)$

Nothing really changes if you add a exponent $r$ because the conjugate of a product is the product of the conjugates.